# How to restore a Duplicity backup to a new host?

Tags: linux, backup, backup-restoration, gpg, duplicity

- Had a catastrophic failure on a RAID array and lost everything.
- Have a full set of backups on S3 via duplicity (2003 files), encrypted with GPG.
- I have the passphrase and a copy of the private key used to encrypt the backups.
- I have imported the private key on the new host with `gpg --import-key KEYNAME`. `gpg --list-keys` gives me the `KEYID`. We'll say it's 123456.
- Downloaded all files from S3 to a fresh local host.
- When I try to list the files in the backup with `duplicity list-current-files file:///mnt/Media/backups --encrypt-key 123456` the result is:

`Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...
GnuPG passphrase: 
Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20111105T191036Z.sigtar.gpg to local cache.
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID ABCDEFG
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
===== End GnuPG log =====`

What step(s) am I missing? The RSA key referenced in the GnuPG log (ex: ABCDEF) is different than the ID of the key I imported (ex: 123456), is that related to the issue?

My test restores when I initially set up the backups all worked, but I realize now it's because the keys were already available on the backed up host. But because the original host is toast, restoring to a brand new host is all new to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**send backup secret-key from BAK-SERVER to RESTORE-SERVER**

```
#ON BAK-SERVER
gpg --list-keys
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys bak-key-name > bak-key-name.secret.asc
cat bak-key-name.secret.asc |nc -l BAK-SERVER_IP 12345


#ON Restore-SERVER

nc BAK-SERVER_IP 12345 > bak-key-name.secret.asc
gpg --import bak-key-name.secret.asc
```

**get encrypt-key : for example 05AB3DF5**

gpg --list-keys

```
/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   2048R/05AB3DF5 2013-09-19
uid                  Your Name <your_email@example.com>
sub   2048R/32866E3B 2013-09-19
```

**backup on BAK-SERVER**

```
PASSPHRASE="passphrase_for_GPG" duplicity  full --encrypt-key 05AB3DF5  /source BAK_URL
```

**restore on RESTORE-SERVER**

```
PASSPHRASE="passphrase_for_GPG" duplicity  restore --encrypt-key 05AB3DF5  BAK_URL /source-restore
```

**refer:**
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-duplicity-with-gpg-to-securely-automate-backups-on-ubuntu

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. If the original server has been completely blown up, am I to understand that the backups are completely inaccessible?